# How do I pass a generated variable from one html file to another

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass one variable from an html file to another. The variable is generated as a random three digit number.

```
   fn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
   sn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
   tn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();

   combinedcode = fn + sn + tn;
```

```js
var fn;
var sn;
var tn;
var combinedcode;

function devcode() {
   fn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
    sn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
    tn =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
    
     combinedcode = fn + sn + tn;
    document.getElementById("activationcode").innerHTML = combinedcode;
}
```

```html
<body onload="devcode()">
  <h1 id="activationcode">we</h1>
</body>
```

I generated there as you can see there is a variable with generated numbers. But then there is another html file that is looking for the same code. The generated code was called to generate by one html file. So I am trying to get that same code on the another html file. Both files are linked to the same JavaScript file. But when I try to get the code in the other file, it says "undefined". I think as it is assigning variables at the beginning, then when the new HTML file starts, it assign them again. But the HTML file that the data/code is being given/passed assigns the variables again, but doesn't call the `devcode()`function, which gives the value, but then the code would be different because it is randomly generated.

It would be appreciated if you could show me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are two different HTML files, even though they include the same JS file, the variables need to be set again.  Since you want the same values that was generated before, you can try one of these methods:

1. You can use JavaScript to redirect with GET parameters.

```js
location.href="./target_file.html?activationcode="+devcode();
```

2. Since this is an activation code, it may need to be more secure, so you can do the same except with a POST request, like this:

```html
<form action="target_file.php" method="post" id="activate">
    <input type="hidden" id="code"/>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("code").value=devCode();
    document.getElementById("activate").submit();
</script>
```

Please note that option 2 only works if you have PHP or something that works with POST requests.

3. Store the values in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.  Set a key and give it a value, and on the other file, get that key.  For example,

```js
// file1.html
// this is the javascript

localStorage.setItem("myvar","setvalue");
```

```js
// file2.html
// this is also javascript

var myvar=localStorage.getItem("myvar");
```

`getItem` will return `null` if the key is not found.

Comment: I think I might use option 3. In localStorage.setItem, what am I suppose to put in the parameters? Also, what do I put in the parameters for localStorage.getItem?

Comment: OK.  You can upvote and accept if it works for you, and if it doesn't, you can comment and I will try to help you.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh I accidentally didn't finish typing the full comment was suppose to be : I think I might use option 3. In localStorage.setItem, what am I suppose to put in the parameters? Also, what do I put in the parameters for localStorage.getItem?

Comment: `setItem` takes 1. the key name and 2. the value.  `getItem` takes just the key name.  You can see what's in the `localStorage` by opening the devtools (ctrl+shift+i), then clicking the `>>`, and then selecting `Application`, and then `Local Storage` in the left menu, and then your site.  Using that method you can see what is inside localStorage, and you can add/remove/edit keys

Comment: So is this all in one JS file linked to file1.html and file2.html? Also, is the key name basically the variable name? Also, if I wanted to alert **myvar**'s value, I would just put **myvar** as a variable that contains the key?

Comment: It doesn't need to be in one JS file, and the key name is not necessarily the variable name.  If you want to alert the value that has the key `myvar`, then `alert(localStorage.getItem("myvar"));`  On the other hand, if you want to alert the *variable* `myvar`, `alert(myvar);`